# Textbox.value as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy an input in a textbox and transform this in a variable that will be used as a range. With the code described below i'm facing error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set. If you have a better way to do this, please let me know.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As String
Dim rangeA As Range
Dim rangeB As Range
Dim rangeC As Range
Dim rangeD As Range
Dim rangeE As Range

rng = TextBoxA.Value

If IsNumeric(RangeboxA.Value) Then
On Error Resume Next
Set rangeA = Sheets("Plan1").Range(RangeboxA.Value)
On Error GoTo 0
If rangeA Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Range A inválido"

End If

rangeA.Select
Selection.Cut
rangeA.Offset(0, rng).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

rng = TextBoxB.Value


 Range("B3:E3").Select
 Selection.Cut
 Range("B3").Offset(0, rng).Select

     ActiveSheet.Paste

rng = TextBoxC.Value


Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B4").Offset(0, rng).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

rng = TextBoxD.Value


Range("B5:E5").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B5").Offset(0, rng).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

rng = TextBoxE.Value


Range("B6:E6").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B6").Offset(0, rng).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: What will be input into the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is interesting.  First, we are picking up `RangeboxA.value`.

To successfully use this within `Range()`, it should look something like:

```
A1:B9
```

but this kind of string will always fail `IsNumeric()` so RangeA never gets `Set` and the `Select` will always fail.

Now if `RangeboxA.value` has a value like:

```
17
```

then `Isnumeric()` will be true, but then:

```
Set rangeA = Sheets("Plan1").Range(RangeboxA.Value)
```

will fail.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed isNumeric() to if not isNull() and now its working.